# strict mode while using grouped category hichart plugin throws error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i am trying to use http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

i tried to include a strict mode inside the grouped-categories.js as following

```
    (function() {
    "use strict";
    jQuery.myNamespace.declare("viz.thirdparty.plugins.grouped_categories-master.grouped-categories");

// existing plugin code goes here
    }());
```

while the plugin renders a chart correctly while using a non strict mode, it throws the following exception when i try to use along with this mode.

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'parent' of Accessories
    at buildTree (plugins/grouped_categories-master/grouped-categories.js:90:18)
    at buildTree
```

any way to clear this error?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: unfortunately it is integrated as a part of my environment that i couldn replicate in a fiddle.

Comment: Honestly we have no chance to repliacate that issue without live demo.